GitHub Actions Maven Build Failing with "relative path" Error After Dynamic Version Update
I'm working on a project where we use GitHub Actions to automate our Maven build process. We dynamically set the version number in the format projectversion-runID-runNumber, like 8.1.0-9761957358-18.  We include that runID in the build version so the deploy workflow can parse it out and download artifacts from the build workflow.
In our build workflow, we use mvn versions:set to update the versions. However, the command is failing with a "relative path" error specifically for the submodules which refer to the module poms as parents with ../../pom.xml. The pom files of those modules, which refer to the parent pom with ../pom.xml, seem to have no problem.  Here are the details:
Error Message:
[ERROR] Child module ... of ... cannot be found in the workspace
[ERROR] The POM for ... is missing, no dependency information available
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example.project.submodule: Could not find artifact com.example.project:module:pom:8.1.0-9761957358-18 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

File Structure:
project-root/
│
├── pom.xml
├── module1/
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── modules/
│       ├── submodule1/
│       │   └── pom.xml
│       ├── submodule2/
│       │   └── pom.xml

Workflow Steps:
name: Build and Publish

on:
  push:
    paths-ignore: ['.github/**']
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set Up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          java-version: 11
          distribution: 'temurin'
          cache: maven

      - name: Set Version
        run: |
          mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=8.1.0-${{ github.run_id }}-${{ github.run_number }} -DgenerateBackupPoms=false

I've verified that the POM files do exist in the local repository, which I believe is the first place Maven looks. We incorporate the runID into the build version so we can parse out the run ID from the tag we create from it. This lets the GitHub deploy workflow download artifacts created from the build workflow.
POM File Examples:
Parent POM (pom.xml):
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
  <version>8.1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>module1</module>
  </modules>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
Module POM (module1/pom.xml):

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
    <version>8.1.0</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.project.module1</groupId>
  <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>modules/submodule1</module>
  </modules>
</project>
Submodule POM (module1/modules/submodule1/pom.xml):

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.example.project.module1</groupId>
    <version>8.1.0</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.project.module1</groupId>
  <artifactId>submodule1</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>

Things I've tried:

Replacing the versions:set command with mvn dependency:tree
and encountered the same "relative path" error.
Adding an rm -rf of the github action runner's local maven repo, to
make sure the maven cache was cleared, and it didn't help.
Taking out the runID in the build version numbers.  Same problem.
Individually installing all the poms explicitly, with
mvn install -N for each module.  No dice.
Doublechecked that the groupIds and artifactIds, and versions listed in
the parent sections matched what was in the parent pom.xml referred to.
This workflow did run somehow before, but then someone did a merge one
day and all the builds started failing this way.  I'm wondering if it
was maybe accessing something cached, but not sure how.
Building the code from the commit before that merge still
resulted in the same error.
Building the code locally in a Windows 10 VM using a shell script that uses the same repositor and pom files works.
We reproduced the error by write protecting one of the pom files, setting the versions, then removing the write protection and trying to set them again. It's possible this is happening earlier in the build somehow, but not sure how to troubleshoot if that's happening.

Any insights on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

The simple question is why using relativePath>../../.. change the structure of your project accordingly ..make simply a pom.xml on the level modules/ and furthermore in your project-root make a pom.xml which is the parent of underlaying modules and don't try to change the name parent-pom.xml or alike... Do you have a link to the project?

@khmarbaise Sorry, that was a Copilot-related mistake... it's pom.xml in the actual project, not parent-pom.xml ...I can't link to the actual project, since it's proprietary.  Trying to post the relevant info.

The relativePath like this:  <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath> do not make sense... create a sub level pom which brings you back to defaults... so you can omit the relativePath also <module>modules/submodule1</module> why having the directory modules? if you like to have it ... just make a pom on the level modules ... and you can define it like <module>modules</modules>... Example of multi module build with several levels: https://github.com/khmarbaise/rpn-calculator

@khmarbaise Thanks for your input.  I get that  defaults to ../pom.xml, and if the parent pom is there, you can omit relativePath, but, if you can't change the location of the parent pom with something like ../../pom.xml (allowing for the extra "modules" directory), what's the purpose of relativePath?  I can try adding a third level of pom files in there, but I'm not convinced that should be necessary.

The question is not if it's necessary but's it's easier to handle... the other question is why do you have that supplemental directory in between which in consequence makes no sense... ?

@khmarbaise Trying to get an existing legacy codebase building in github actions.  Was previously building fine as is with Bamboo.  I don't want to change the way it's structured unless necessary.

Is this https://chatgpt.com/share/aeb1e174-452a-4b82-8f02-b2eec83b5eb7 helpful?

@oOosys Definitely tried ChatGPT already... the mvn validate was new, but that fails with the same error as trying to set the version or viewing the dependency tree.

@sdanzig : sometimes you need to ask the question from another perspective or ask for further details. Yesterday I had got bullshit code as answer ... so I changed the question from requesting translation from turtle code to svg image of the canvas and asked for python code using the svgwrite module ... As result I have got the code writing valid and proper svg image code (which the AI could run itself to get the svg code as translation, but didn't). It's some work ... but often you arrive at a solution faster than asking elsewhere.

@sdanzig : I had a 500 bounty question lately on stackoverflow ... and many, many answers, ... finally asking the AI to provide further details about the code and what and how it works I have arrived at what I couldn't get proper and not misleading help with in spite of the bounty.

I figured out what was going wrong.
The parent module is actually a subdirectory in a git repository.  We needed a pom.xml at the root of that repository just for keeping the dependency graph up to date so Dependabot could work.  All it was is a minimal aggregator pom file that just pointed to the submodules, including the parent module mentioned in this post.  The root-level aggregator pom was not intended to be part of a build though.
A step earlier in the workflow was setting the versions in another "parent project".  We eventually noticed that when that project's versions were being set, it was first searching for a "local aggregator root", finding the pom we weren't intending to use, and finding the other parent projects through that, setting versions in those too.  By the time it tried to set versions in the other parent projects, the versions were no longer as expected.
mvn versions:set, however, has this processFromLocalAggregationRoot option, that defaults to true.  So I went in the workflow and added
-DprocessFromLocalAggregationRoot=false

to all the usages of mvn versions:set
That fixed it and allowed us to keep the pom file for Dependabot.

Glad to see that you have figured it out ... it was the purpose of my comments to show you ways to arrive at the solution yourself. Discussing things with "stupid" AI can often have the "maid effect" so you discover the solution while explaining the problem in an easy to understand way to someone else. In other words I consider your answer as confirmation that bounties are of a very limited value ...
